# Opensource data mine tools, searching for a good option (GNU data mining apps)

Tags: open-source, data-mining, gnome, classification, cluster-analysis

I want to test some apps for data mining in GNU/Linux Debian, I downloaded "Gnome Data Mine Tools" from http://www.togaware.com/datamining/gdatamine/; I followed the instructions, I installed the app(s) and then it says that you should run the command: **gdmapriori**, but, it throws me this error:

```
/usr/local/share/gdmtools/gdmapriori.py:46: DeprecationWarning: The popen2 module is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.
import popen2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/share/gdmtools/gdmapriori.py", line 480, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/local/share/gdmtools/gdmapriori.py", line 475, in main
AprioriApp().mainloop()
File "/usr/local/share/gdmtools/gdmapriori.py", line 81, in __init__"apriori_app")
File "/usr/local/share/gdmtools/glutil.py", line 134, in __init__
gnome.ui.App.__init__(self, appname=name, title=title)
TypeError: Required argument 'name' (pos 1) not found
```

What should I do? do you know another good GNU tools for data mining? thanks in advance

Comment: You want GNU tools?  GNU GPL-licensed tools?  GTK-based tools?  Specifically *Gnome* tools?  This question is very confusing.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, actually I want opensource tools, sorry for the name, I've just picked up from that website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very popular open source data mining project is [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).  From your clarifications, I think this is what you want (it's Java-based, and not Gnome, but it's opensource, which is what you wanted?).

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to test it, it looks great!

Answer (score 2):

ELKI, http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/ and available as package `elki` in Debian and Ubuntu is a rather active project. It focuses on cluster analysis and outlier detection, which are really weak in Weka. So the two complement each other mostly (Weka is strong in classification and machine learning).

Comment: That sounds great! Im goint to test it now, cool, Debian

Comment: It's research/development software though. Not end-user. Takes some time to get used to, and experience in data preprocessing before use.